# ios - (Push Notification) When I call getNotificationSettings alertSetting is returning NotSupported

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

When I call

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings
```

the alertSetting is returning **"Not Supported"**. Here is the callback.

```
Notification settings: <UNNotificationSettings: 0x17408be50; authorizationStatus: Authorized, notificationCenterSetting: Enabled, soundSetting: Enabled, badgeSetting: Enabled, lockScreenSetting: Enabled, **alertSetting: NotSupported**, carPlaySetting: Enabled, alertStyle: Banner>
```

What does that means?

I'm testing on an iPhone with iOS 10.3.2.

Comment: It means the user has all kinds of notification settings enabled EXCEPT for displaying alerts.. So when they receive a notification, they get a badge, a banner, etc.. but they will NOT get an alert on the lock-screen or in-app. Depending on what permissions you've requested, this may work. To get it to not show "Not Supported", go to settings and change it from just banners to banners and alerts for notifications..

Comment: Do you mean Settings -> Notifications -> My app ->  Alerts? I have done that but didn't work.

This really don't let my app to receive push notifications on lock-screen?

I just want to get "Enable"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is means that the setting is not available to your app. You can find more information here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsetting

Comment: How do I enable the setting?

Comment: Going to Settings > <Your app name> > Notifications